# how to save data on database without chose and read image

Tags: php, image, laravel

I'm trying to save my data with form, where i'm not choosing image in the form because its not yet needed. But I'm still stuck with an error **Image source not readable**.
My form has 'enctype' => 'multipart / form-data'. What is the alternative, so that I can save data in database without chose and upload the image in the form. Thanks for your answer.

view form script :

```
      {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'BarangContr@addData', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) }}
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('Nama Barang', 'Nama Barang :') }}
            {{ Form::text('nama_barang',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'width:500px']) }}

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ Form::label('Harga Barang', 'Harga Barang :') }}
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Rp</span>
                {{ Form::text('harga_barang',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'width:460px']) }}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              {{ Form::label('Jumlah Barang', 'Jumlah Barang :') }}
              <div class="input-group">
                {{ Form::text('jumlah',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'width:500px']) }}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('image', 'Pilih gambar') }}
                {{ Form::file('image', null ) }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer">
            {{ Form::submit('Simpan', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Simpan dan Publikasi</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Batal</button>
          </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

and this method in my contoller for save data :

```
public function addData()
{
   $datas = new BarangModel;
   $datas -> kode_barang  = strtotime(Carbon\Carbon::now());

   $dataGambar = new GambarModel;
   $dataGambar -> kode_gambar   = $datas->kode_barang;
   $dataGambar -> kategori      = 'barang';
   $dataGambar->save();
   Session::flash('message', 'Berhasil menambahkan barang !');
   return Redirect::to('/barang');
}
```

Comment: don't you think, you have posted wrong controller method? In your form you are sending form to `simpan` method, but you have posted `addData()` method

Comment: sorry, I missed it. I just change the name of the method before post in here, but it is the method that I use when submit the form. Is there any way submit the form without selecting an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide your destination file path inside save method

```
Image::make($request->file('image')->getRealPath());
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/uploading-image-null-on-laravel-50

Comment: I mean that the value of the image or path remains null, then save data in the database without any input that I chose and upload an image.